# Find merge commits that will contribute to the next release in git and their top-level issue number

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-flow, release-management

Assuming the following tree and commit messages and issues

```
         c---e---g--- feature
        /         
  -a---b---d---f---h--- dev
   |        \     /
production   i--j

Commit messages
b: Fixes #41
d: Some commit message that is not worth notifying
f: Add migration for #43
h: Merge pull request #42 from /feature/linkedin-registration 
i: Merge pull request #51 from /tk/oauth-service
j: Merge pull request #52 from /tk/linkedin-controller

Issues
#41
#42 (Composite issue that we call a "Feature")
-- #51 (issue of #42)
-- #52 (issue of #42)
#43
```

Here's the goal I ultimately want to achieve formulated as a user story

```
As a (dev) Release Manager
When I open a new Release
I want to identify the issues corresponding to the commits of this release
So I am aware of which top-level issues will be a part of the next release 
and I can prepare notes of what is going to be released
```

We are using git flow, and because we've recently changed the way we split work (we are using epics and nested epics with zenhub wihch I represented above using a "Composite issue") it's become difficult to determine which features will be part of our next release. We want to be able to more easily determine what will be part of our next production release when opening a new release

So in the graph above : 
- our production branch is at `a` : this is the code that is live now
- opening a release branch means forking from the HEAD of our development branch (currently at `h`) 
  - while ignoring commits from unmerged feature branches (`c`, `e`, `g`) 
  - including the ones from merged feature branches (`i`, `j` with `h` being the merge commit)

I need to

1. collect the relevant commits that will be part of the release branch I open from `h` and I need to collect the commit messages of
   `b`, `d`, `f`, `h` (I do not need `i`, `j` since they are commits of the a feature branch but I only care about the final merge commit `h` or commits that were made directly in the `dev` branch
2. I want to extract issue numbers (when looking at the commit messages : `#41`, `#42`, `#43` so that I can manually open those issues, and by going up the epic chain find out what the code really was about (I don't want to extract `#51` and `#52`)

Getting 2 shouldn't be a problem with a small `grep`, but how can I filter commits as described in `1.` ?

(Also I'm open to comments/answers that would suggest a completely different way of solving the "release manager user story")

Answer (score 1):

As I suspect you already know (from "getting 2 shouldn't be a problem"), when you want to tie a commit to some external administrative record like what issue number it's addressing or who's signed off on it or whatever, you use a "trailer" on the commit message.  For bulk work you can use `git format-patch` and `git interpret-trailers` to help with the wrangling.

#1 is simple: `git rev-list --first-parent production..dev` will list the commits, basically everything else generates commit lists using the rev-list machinery.  So for a 
starter kit you can get all the trailers from those commits with

```
rm -rf ${work=`mktemp -d`}
git format-patch -o $work --first-parent production..dev
git interpret-trailers --parse $work/*
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to git format-patch. However this does not seem to work as intended, and it does not show at all merge commits messages. I tried removing the `--first-parent`flag but it did not work either. I do not see the patches like `Merge pull request #25 from MyOrg/feature/11-some-feature`
Also `git interpret-trailers --parse $work/* does not produce any output despite having some patches in the folder ?

Comment: `git interpret-trailers` gets you only the trailers. No trailers, no output.